# GRC file meta sink how

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I'm new to GRC.  I want to modify the attached config to replace the "file sink" at the bottom of the image with "file meta sink", so I can use a program to read the header and then the complex samples. I guess I might need a different stream adapter, but it is not clear which one or how.

Help please.

Thanks,
Don

[image]

Comment: so, what's the problem? just connect the file meta sink! You're not actually asking a *precise* question, so we can't answer anything :(

Comment: For some reason it was not connecting.  I retried it today and it works. I hate when that happens.  I'm now looking at a hexdump of the file created by file_meta_sink.  If I cannot completed parse it I'll post  new question.